# Encurta/Camuflar texto muito grande dentro de uma grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho essa linha da grid que pega a descrição de uma mensagem, porém é muito grande as vezes e fica quebrando o layout da grid, gostaria de saber se é possível encurtar a mensagem e/ou camuflar a mensagem em link.

Ou seja pegar a **mensagem** e substituir por um **Visulizar**

Segue código:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ÚLTIMA MENSAGEM">
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<ItemTemplate>
     <a href="cicloObjetivo.aspx?Cod=<%# Eval("OcIDescr")%>" style="color: #0000FF;">
          <%# Eval("OcIDescr").ToString()%>'</a>
 </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Grid:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: dentro de ItemStyle, adiciona o tamanho que você quer na coluna: `<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="50px" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão para você:

- Na classe que você possui a propriedade de descrição **(OcIDescr)** você pode adicionar uma nova propriedade que seria a descrição resumida, quando o usuário clicar nela você abriria um modal mostrando o texto completo.

  ```
  public string OcIDescrResumida
  {
      get
      {
          return !string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(OcIDescr) ? OcIDescr.Substring(0, 20) + "..." : string.empty
      }
  }
  ```

Não se esqueça de substituir seu trecho de código para utilizar essa nova propriedade.